# Node JS, Express, MSSQL, Socket IO

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js

How to configure socket with sql database? 
What a actually need is get every changes in database to my server.
I am using npm MSSQL and Socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `mssql` package through NPM

```
 npm install mssql
```

here's a link to its [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql)

```
var sql = require('mssql');

sql.connect("mssql://username:password@localhost/database").then(function() {
// Query 

new sql.Request().query('select * from mytable').then(function(recordset) {
    console.dir(recordset);
}).catch(function(err) {
    // ... query error checks 
});

// Stored Procedure 

new sql.Request()
.input('input_parameter', sql.Int, value)
.output('output_parameter', sql.VarChar(50))
.execute('procedure_name').then(function(recordsets) {
    console.dir(recordsets);
}).catch(function(err) {
    // ... execute error checks 
});

// ES6 Tagged template literals (experimental) 

sql.query`select * from mytable where id =    ${value}`.then(function(recordset) {
    console.dir(recordset);
}).catch(function(err) {
    // ... query error checks 
});
}).catch(function(err) {
// ... connect error checks 
});
```